# Unzip 4gb file in c#

Tags: c#, zip, gzip, compression

I am using sharp lib for zip and unzip. It works fine upto 4GB file so looking for some .net framework solution. I tried Gzipcompression in dotnet. That too fails to uncompress 4gb files.
Do you know any other zip library which handles large files.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) will handle ZIP64 archives (>4.2GB) correctly, in 100% managed code.  It also (from my testing) has a dramatically better feature set and does a better job than the framework libraries for compression (ie: equal or better perf. with much smaller files - often about 1/3rd the size of the framework's compression routines).

Answer (score 5):

The 4 Gb limitation was removed in .NET 4.0, so you can use the classes in `System.IO.Compression` namespace.

> The compression algorithms in
>   System.IO.Compression have been
>   improved in .NET 4.  DeflateStream and
>   GZipStream no longer inflate already
>   compressed data.  This means that in
>   many cases you’ll see better
>   compression ratios when using these
>   streams on .NET 4.  We’ve also removed
>   the 4 GB size limit, so you can now
>   compress streams over 4 GB in length.

From: [What's New in BCL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2009/05/22/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-1-justin-van-patten.aspx)

If you cannot target the .NET 4.0 framework then I'm afraid I can't be of any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If appearance is not an issue, you can use Shell FolderItems (shell32.dll), the only drawbacks are that it's a little tricky to use and you get a Windows progress dialog rather than a callback routine.